# Excel 2010- formatting a number with a decimal to a percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a group of numbers that already have a decimal in them. Example 68.77 when I try to format to make this a percentage I get this 6877%. How do I get it to keep the decimal in the number? I am looking for 68.77%

Answer (score 3):

Type 100 anywhere on the sheet and copy it.

Then select your numbers and hit paste special - divide

Now they can all be turned into the correct percentage.

Comment: It seems to me that this would change the numeric to a text cell making it problematic to use in a later formula.

Comment: @Cmom I completely altered my answer due to mdpc being correct in the above comment. Cmom - I would urge you to delete your "that worked" comment here and re-evaluate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the numeric cell format for use in later computations, I might generate another column using the formula something like =b1/100.0 for all the cells in the new column.  This assumes your problem column is in B.

another suggestion, is that if this is derived from a formula, change the original formula to divide by 100 (or you could multiply by 0.01).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the whole number simply with a "%" at the end, try this format from the Excel format menu, 'custom' formats: "0.0\%*);(0.0\%);0.0\%*);@*%*)"

Worked for me:

81.3582914270273 = 81.4%